how to set the type of the data, when sending a pandas dataframe to a excel workbook via to_excel()
DataFrame:
RefDate          2023     2024  2025    2026    2027    2028
DataDate                        
02/01/2024  2.4000  1.7100  2.0000  2.0000  1.9000  NaN
03/01/2024  2.4000  1.7100  2.0000  2.0000  1.9000  NaN
04/01/2024  2.4000  1.7000  1.9500  1.9500  1.9100  NaN
05/01/2024  2.4000  1.7000  1.9500  1.9500  1.9100  NaN
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
27/03/2024  NaN 2.1029  2.0000  1.9750  2.0000  2.0000
28/03/2024  NaN 2.1029  2.0000  1.9500  2.0000  2.0000

with pd.ExcelWriter(r'PATH') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='NAME')


Every time I send the df to the excel workbook, all the data goes as text. How do I send it as numeric or float data?
I tried:
column_list = []
for column in df.columns:
    column_list.append(column)

for column in column_list:
    df[column] = pd.to_numeric(df[column], errors='coerce')

I also tried:
dtype_mapping = {}
for coluna in lista_colunas:
    dtype_mapping[coluna] = float

df.to_excel('dados.xlsx', index=False, dtype=dtype_mapping)

but couldn't make it work
edit[1] Original DataFrame (before pivoting):
        Data    RefData     Value
0   02/01/2024  2023-01-01  2.9233
1   02/01/2024  2024-01-01  1.5500
2   02/01/2024  2025-01-01  2.0000
3   02/01/2024  2026-01-01  2.0000
4   02/01/2024  2027-01-01  2.0000
... ... ... ...
300 28/03/2024  2024-01-01  1.8900
301 28/03/2024  2025-01-01  2.0000
302 28/03/2024  2026-01-01  2.0000
303 28/03/2024  2027-01-01  2.0000
304 28/03/2024  2028-01-01  2.0000

 df_pivot = df.pivot_table(index='DataDate', columns='RefData', values='value')


the df is a diferent one, it has diferent data but the structure is the same

Show your current column dtypes.

df.columns = Index(['2023', '2024', '2025', '2026', '2027', '2028'], dtype='object', name='RefDate')
df.columns.dtype = dtype('O')

Ah, I wasn't clear enough - I didn't mean the type of the column index, I meant the dtypes associated with each column. This should be accessible via df.dtypes.

RefData
2023    object
2024    object
2025    object
2026    object
2027    object
2028    object
dtype: object

But also, that dtype('O') is already a problem. Those should be integers or dates, not objects.

Right, so there's your issue - everything is an object, so all of your current dtypes make no sense. It's no wonder than an export to Excel also doesn't make sense.

do you know what could i do about it?

Make a minimum reproducible example showing how your current dataframe was actually constructed. There will be errors in there that you have not shown here.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

My DataFrame has many dtyping flaws. I decided to not resolve them all. But for this specific matter (having everything as an object after pivoting the table), you can use df_pivot = df_pivot.astype("TYPE").
